# smtplib does not send text messages anymore

Tags: python, smtplib

I've been messing with smtplib sending text messages. It's been working fine so far but I spammed myself by putting sendmail() in a for loop like a hundred times and it worked fine but then it threw an error and since then I cannot send texts anymore. I know what I did is probably volatile but could someone explain why this would happen? Any knowledge and info you could share would be awesome. Or if anything was not clear I will elaborate. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You asking how spam detection work? As I know, if you send same email from same IP many times, definitely your IP/email/pattern/checksum will go into a some sort of blacklist. That blacklist will be shared between many antispam software/company. And threshold are different. After that, receiver will eject your email or mark your email as spam. So don't do that. You will be marked.

Comment: So is there any way around this at all?